# Replace part of string with values that are matched from an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to figure out how I can fill in some values from objects in a string in order to eventually perform some math. I can get the data and match values from between the brackets, but I am stuck on where to go from here or if there is another way to do it that would be better practice. Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
var array = [{name: M, value: 45},{name: F, value: 23},{name: L, value: 9}]
var string = '( 2 * [M] ) * ( 5 / [F] ) * ( 100 + [L] )'
```

To simplify my explanation, I need to take that string formula, and plugin in the value of "M" into "[M]", and the value of "F" into "[F]", and so on...

Comment: You can use template literals. they can be used to to inject values in a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this. Thank you.

```js
var variables = [{name: "M", value: 45}, {name: "F", value: 23}, {name: "L", value: 9}];
var equation = '( 2 * [M] ) * ( 5 / [F] ) * ( 100 + [L] )';

const getfinalEquation = (array, equationWithVars) => {
  let finalEquation = equationWithVars;
  
  array.forEach(item => {
    finalEquation = finalEquation.replaceAll(`[${item.name}]`, item.value);
  })
  
  return finalEquation;
}

console.log(getfinalEquation(variables, equation));
```

Comment: But that leaves `[45]`

Comment: @LuisAFK Ughh, sorry... I forgot to remove the brackets. Thanks for noticing. Edited...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nerdamer](https://nerdamer.com/). It's for doing formulas and stuff.

```js
let vars = {M: 45, F: 23, L: 9};
let equation = '( 2 * M ) * ( 5 / F ) * ( 100 + L )';

console.log(
  equation,
  '=',
  nerdamer(
    equation,
    vars
  )
  .evaluate()
  .text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
```

If you want a simpler way, just do:

```js
let vars = {M: 45, F: 23, L: 9};
let equation = '( 2 * [M] ) * ( 5 / [F] ) * ( 100 + [L] )';

function calculate(equation, vars)
{
  let newEquation = equation.replaceAll(/\[[A-Z]\]/gi, function(v)
  {
    return vars[v[1]];
  });
  
  return eval(newEquation);
}

console.log(calculate(equation, vars));
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, do you know of a "vanilla" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one line solution:

```js
const array = [{name: 'M', value: 45},{name: 'F', value: 23},{name: 'L', value: 9}]
const string = "( 2 * [M] ) * ( 5 / [F] ) * ( 100 + [L] )";

const calculate = (array) => array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>{ return accumulator.replace(`[${currentValue.name}]`, currentValue.value)}, string);

console.log('Result: ', eval(calculate(array)));
```